# Application crashing because of a NullPointerException in a custon ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences, android-dialog

I'm working with a listview which on click opens a dialog box which contains an edittext and a button. On button click, the value entered in the editText is saved in a textView from listview item which had been pressed before. The problem is that the value wasn't saved anymore if I reopened the application. I tried to make it save using sharedPrefences but it's crashing and shows nullpointerexception and can't deal with it.

**NoteAdapter.java:**

```
 package com.cngcnasaud.orar;

    import java.util.Arrays;

    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class NoteAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        String[] result;
        Context context;
        int[] imageId;
        private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
        private Dialog dialog;
        String[] savedEntries;
        String[] saved = null;

        public NoteAdapter(Note note, String[] saved, String[] prgmNameList) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            result = prgmNameList;
            context = note;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if (saved == null) {
                savedEntries = new String[result.length];
                Arrays.fill(savedEntries, "");
            } else
                savedEntries = saved;

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return result.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return savedEntries[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public class Holder {
            TextView tv;
            ImageView img;
            public TextView text;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            final Holder holder = new Holder();
            View rowView;
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.note_items, null);
            holder.tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            holder.text.setText(savedEntries[position]);
            holder.img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog = new Dialog(context);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
                    dialog.setTitle("Materie:" + result[position]);

                    final EditText txtMode = (EditText) dialog
                            .findViewById(R.id.dialog);
                    Button btnSave = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bsave);

                    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            String data = txtMode.getText().toString();
                            holder.text.setText(data);

                            savedEntries[position] = data;

                            dialog.dismiss();
                            Log.d("data", data);
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();
                }

            });
            return rowView;
        }

    }
```

**logcat:**

```
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947): Process: com.cngcnasaud.orar, PID: 947
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at com.cngcnasaud.orar.NoteAdapter.getView(NoteAdapter.java:76)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-19 04:14:32.130: E/AndroidRuntime(947):  at com.android.internal.os.
```

**Line 76 in NoteAdapter.java:**

```
holder.text.setText(savedEntries[position]);
```

**Adapter's constructor - Note.java:**

```
package com.cngcnasaud.orar;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.Menu;

import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Note extends Activity {

    public static final ListAdapter NoteAdapter = null;
    ListView lv;
    Context context;
    ArrayList<?> prgmName;
    TextView text;

    public static String[] prgmNameList = { "Romana   - ", "Matematica   - ",
            "Lb. Engleza   - ", "Lb. Germana/Franceza - ", "Istorie   - ",
            "Geografie   - ", "Biologie   - ", "Fizica   - ", "Ed. Fizica   - " };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.note_listview);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        context = this;

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(new NoteAdapter(this, prgmNameList, null));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        NoteAdapter adapter = (NoteAdapter) lv.getAdapter();

        // Variable is public for clarity.
        String toSave = EncodeDecode.encode(adapter.savedEntries);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("LV Data",
                MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("TVEntries", toSave);
        editor.commit();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("LV Data", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String encoded = prefs.getString("TVEntries", "");

        String[] entries;
        if (encoded.equals(""))
            entries = null;
        else
            entries = EncodeDecode.decode(encoded);

        NoteAdapter adapter = (NoteAdapter) lv.getAdapter();
        adapter.savedEntries = entries;
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        super.onResume();
    }

}
```

**EncodeDecode.java:**

```
package com.cngcnasaud.orar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.lang.StringBuffer;

public class EncodeDecode
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    //Test functionality.
    String[] toEncode = {"a?b","c,d,", "asdas,dasd?,,,,,", "asdsad*\t      "};
    String encodedString = encode(toEncode);
    String[] decodedArray = decode(encodedString);
    System.out.println("Original Array: " + Arrays.toString(toEncode));
    System.out.println("Encoded String: " + encodedString);
    System.out.println("Decoded Array: " + Arrays.toString(decodedArray));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Testing equality of the arrays.....");
    if(encode(toEncode).equals(encode(decodedArray)))
      System.out.println("Passed!");
    else
       System.out.println("Failed :(!");
  }

  /**  
   *  Function: encode
   *  --------------------
   *  Encode a String array into a single String.
   *  
   *  toEncode: the String array to be encoded.
   *
   *  returns: the encoded string.
   */
  public static String encode(String[] toEncode)
  {
    StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i = 0; i < toEncode.length; i++)
    {
      /*Retrieve a representation of the current string element that is
      easier to modify.*/
      StringBuffer curString = new StringBuffer(toEncode[i]);
      for(int j = 0; j < curString.length(); j++)
        //If we see a "break" character, prepend another "break" character to it.
        if(curString.charAt(j) == '?')
        {
          curString.insert(j, '?');
          j++;
        }
        //If we see a delimiter character, prepend "break" character to it.
        else if(curString.charAt(j) == ',')
        {
          curString.insert(j, '?');
          j++;
        }

      //Add the delimiter to the encoded string.
      strBuf.append(curString + ",");

    }
    return strBuf.toString();
  }

  /**  
   *   Function: decode
   *  --------------------
   *  Decode an encoded string into its original array..
   *  
   *  toDecode: the String to be decoded.
   *
   *  returns: the decoded String array.
   */
  public static String[] decode(String toDecode)
  {
    /*We utilize an ArrayList, since the exact number of 
    string elements is inderterminate*/
    ArrayList<String> decoded = new ArrayList<String>();

    /*Retrieve a representation of the current string element that is
    easier to modify.*/
    StringBuffer encodedStr = new StringBuffer(toDecode);

    //The starting point of the current isolated string to add/append.
    int currIndex = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < encodedStr.length(); i++)
    {
      /*If we see the "break character" remove it, and skip
      the following character*/
      if(encodedStr.charAt(i) == '?')
        encodedStr.deleteCharAt(i);

      /*If we see a delimiter, add what we have amassed
      so far to the list.*/
      else if(encodedStr.charAt(i) == ',')
      {
        decoded.add(encodedStr.substring(currIndex, i));

        //Update the starting point.
        currIndex = i + 1;
      }
    }

    String[] toReturn = new String[decoded.size()];
    return decoded.toArray(toReturn);
  }
}
```

**Line 39 in EncodeDecode:java:**

```
for(int i = 0; i < toEncode.length; i++)
```

Comment: you should take a look at note_items.xml: Is there a textview with the id `textView2` ? Also savedEntries might have been set to null in your code before

Comment: Of course I checked if the id exists and it's correct. It exists and it is correct. I tried too set the savedEntries string = null, but still the same crash and error. To be more explicit, that textView should be null when the app starts, then it should be filled with values by users. Isn't that a problem? Thanks !!!

Comment: and the id is ìnside `note_items` layout? Anyhow add a log before the line that throws NPE and check all the values.

Comment: Yes it is. Can you explain how to add the log?

Comment: You can use android [Log](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) or use System.out.println or alternatively put breakpoint on the error line and run debugger.

Comment: I did it. I opened the perspective and shows NPE at line 76 . Do I have to give you some information from there?

Comment: check values of holder, text and savedEntries. At least one of them is pointing to null.

Comment: So.. here I get this: Value of holder=NoteAdapter$Holder(id = ...) , then text value = TextView , savedEntries = null, and I have convertView = null ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your debugging `savedEntries == null`. That is the reason for the NullPointerException here: `savedEntries[position]`

Since you said that those array-values will be provided by the users later you can for example just add a null check to avoid this problem, something like this:

```
if (savedEntries != null) {
    holder.text.setText(savedEntries[position]);
} else {
    holder.text.setText(""); 
}
```

**Update:**

Looks like you try to look up the textview with the id `textView2` in 2 different layout xmls! One is in `note_items` layout, the other in `note_listview`.

See in **Note Activity**:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.note_listview);

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

See in **NoteAdapter**:

```
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.note_items, null);
    holder.tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    holder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

==> Without even looking at the xml layout (which you didn't include in question) I can tell that this is not good. The reason is you have either textviews id `textView2` in different layouts, which is bad since ids must be unique or `textView2` is simply missing in note_items layout.

Comment: Still crashing and nullpointing in else: `} else {
      holder.text.setText(""); `

Comment: Uy :-) Did I understand your comment wrong that `savedEntries == null` while text & holder != null? To make sure can you add this just before the error line: `Log.d("debugging NPE", "text: " + holder.text + " savedEntries: " + savedEntries);` and let me know what it prints. Because in the end looks like text is null, although you said that the id is right in note_items layout.. weird.

Comment: It looks like it works, but I still get 1 NPE at line 39 in EncodeDecode activity. Can't I change my sharedprefences codes and not to work with this class? Can't you help me with this, please? Thanks a lot !  ** I edited and added EncodeDecode.java in first post.Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

`lv.setAdapter(new NoteAdapter(this, prgmNameList, null))` is the problem. `NoteAdapter`'s constructor expects the *third* argument to be the program list.

In addition, I would recommend creating an empty array in `Note` and passing that in as `NoteAdapter`'s second argument. Then, in your `onStop`, you could simply say `String toSave = EncodeDecode.encode(the_array_you_created);` instead of `String toSave = EncodeDecode.encode(adapter.savedEntries);`

**EDIT**

```
public class Note extends Activity {

...
private String[] savedArray;
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    savedArray = new String[prgmNameList.length];
    lv.setAdapter(new NoteAdapter(this, savedArray, prgmNameList));

}
```

...

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    String toSave = EncodeDecode.encode(savedArray);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("LV Data",
            MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString("TVEntries", toSave);
    editor.commit();
}
....
```

}

Comment: I don't understand you point. Can you be more specific on how to create that empty array and pass it in NoteAdapter's second argument, please?

Comment: @Andrei, added code. My point was that it seems to me the array you're saving things into is passed in as the second argument of the NoteAdapter and the list of programs that you initialize in your activity is the third argument.

Comment: @Andrei, did you mean not working or now working? :)

Comment: I solved the NPE at the textView but now I get another NPE at line 39 in EncodeDecode class. I updated the first post, may you take a look? Thanks !

Comment: hmm, looks like the array you're passing to the encode method is still null. Can you show me what changes you made to the Note class?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51039/discussion-between-neeraj2608-and-andrei)